# The call is ambiguous between two methods or properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dotnetopenauth

I use mvc3/razor,This code is for integrating openID.

When I run the program it is working fine,But When i see the code, red lines gives this popuperror.

The call is ambiguous between two methods or properties
[image]

update:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime encoderType="AntiXssEncoder, Projectname" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>


  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="ProjectnameEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Projectname.csdl|res://*/Data.Projectname.ssdl|res://*/Data.Projectname.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=***\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Projectname;user id=idname;password=***;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
        connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Your screenshot truncates the exact error message. We cannot see between which 2 methods the call is ambiguous. It would have been far better if you posted your code not as screenshot as well as the exact error message you are getting. By the way have you tried running the application? Because sometimes Visual Studio Razor Syntax highlighting and Intellisense is far from perfect.

Comment: Sorry for that,both have same arguments.

Comment: Alright, what happens when you run your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have two references to MVC in your web.config file or you have multiple references to the MVC library.  Check the assemblies section.  You may also want to try a [redirect in your web.config to MVC 3](http://chrisfulstow.com/redirecting-assemblies-in-net) or 4 (whichever one your project targets).

Comment: Yes, it was updated from mvc3 to mvc4. check the question.I updated with webconfig file,

Comment: As far as I can tell your web.config looks to be correct.  Check your references as well to see if you have the correct versions of system.web* assemblies.